# Adjust a crude rate based on observed prevalence within population

Tags: prevalence

I have data such as the below:

| Area | Admissions | Population | Crude rate per 100,000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cambridge | 137,204 | 1,077,382 | 12,735 |
| London | 111,896 | 1,013,985 | 11,035 |

I have been asked to 'adjust the crude rate for prevalence' in these areas. I am only familiar with direct and indirect age standardisation. The prevalence values are Cambridge 7.4% and London 6.4%.

Can anyone advise how they would approach this from this perspective? I have thought of:

Cases/Population/Prevalence*100,000, would this be accurate? The adjustment should take in to account the fact that we would expect more cases in areas with higher prevalence.

Comment: What are "cases" and "prevalence" measuring?  If the "crude rate", i.e. cases/population, is $12.7\%$ in Cambridge, what does it mean that this is higher than the "prevalence" of $7.4\%$? (Most people think London has a population of about $9$m, rather higher than Cambridge at $0.15$m)

Comment: Thanks, the data are dummy data to avoid disclosure. Question is about the general principle of adjusting a crude rate based on the introduction of another variable (e.g. prevalence in the population).

Comment: Could you explain the distinction between this adjustment and simply dividing the rate by the population?

Comment: The confusion here is that prevalence can be translated as 'cases per number of people/population'. So it is not very clear what sort of cases are in your table and how it differs from the cases that relate to the prevalence.

Comment: I've changed the dummy table to relate to 'Admissions' and 'Population' for the rate. So for example is there a way to take the crude rate of hospital admissions (for heart failure, for example) and factor in an adjustment for heart failure recorded prevalence in the region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this.

Instead of *"admissions per population"* you can express it as *"admissions per cases"* (or whatever described by the prevalence)

Then the table will look like:

| Area | Admissions | Population | Cases | Admissions per 100 000 population | Admissions per 100 000 Cases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cambridge | 137 204 | 1 077 382 | 79 726 | 12 735 | 172 094 |
| London | 111 896 | 1 013 985 | 64 895 | 11 035 | 172 426 |

Where you compute $$\text{cases $=$ population $\times$ prevalence}$$ and admissions per cases $$\text{admissions per cases} = \frac{\text{admissions}}{\text{population $\times$ prevalence}}$$

---

Tricky is the situation when you want

> So for example is there a way to take the crude rate of hospital admissions (for heart failure, for example) and factor in an adjustment for heart failure recorded prevalence in the region?

This seems like you are looking at the same type of 'cases' but counted in different ways.

- The *prevalence* is the total amount of cases being **present at** some given **point in time**.
- You seem to be looking for something like *incidence* a rate of cases, the total amount of cases **occuring during** some given **period of time**.

In this case you could divide incidence by prevalence, but then you get a value that has the dimensions of $\text{time}^{-1}$ and the meaning of the number is not so clear (something like a growth of new cases per current cases). If you have a difference between two cities, then this can have different causes (e.g. a relatively large rate can be due to relatively stronger growth, but also due to cases that are short in duration).

This incidence/prevalence would have a different type of interpretation than what we computed in the beginning of this answer. It is not like a fraction or rate among the group of people in the denominator. The incidence might be occurring among the population that is not a case yet. An example where this 'adjustment' might go different is for example [logistic growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#In_ecology:_modeling_population_growth) (like SIR model for evolution of an epidemic) where the growth rate relates both to the current prevalence as well as the remaining population that is not a case. For such models the growth rate scales like $$\text{rate} \propto (\text{population-cases}) \times \text{cases}$$ and might require a different type of adjustment.

Comment: Your overloading of commas to serve both as separators and decimal points makes a confusing table!

Comment: @whuber, I copied the table from the OP. Normally I don't use commas as separator and use spaces instead. Even though there are no decimal points here, I will change it anyway since I didn't really like it either.

Comment: I see.  What confused me is that I was not expecting to see admissions per case expressed in units of $10^{-5},$ because admissions per case ought to be less than 1 but still appreciable.  That is, as a number it's already meaningful and doesn't need to be re-expressed in terms of any other denominator.

Comment: @whuber that's again another issue that I considered myself. I chose to remain with the OP's use of parts-per expression, which can be motivated by a wish to remain conform with the expression of many other (smaller) numbers in the field (I suspect epidemiology), which may be using these type of parts-per expressions.